# Apps Script API Getting a 404 error when using `https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/${fileId}:run`

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I'm trying to run a function in another script file.  Here is my code:

```
function testGet(fileId = "1JjRpqhqJMvXETMMzlYFnuulni6DuwLl9jxlYnGNNm45NwzPXdtcWOK0a") {
  const url = `https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${fileId}/content`;
  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const params = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token,
      "Content-Type": 'application/json'
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(response);
}

function testRun(fileId = "1JjRpqhqJMvXETMMzlYFnuulni6DuwLl9jxlYnGNNm45NwzPXdtcWOK0a") {
  const url = `https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/${fileId}:run`;
  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const query = {
    "function": "tester",
    "parameters": [],
  }
  const params = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token,
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": 'application/json'
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify(query)
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

I am using `testGet()` to make sure the API is able to see the script file and it's functions.  This returns the following response:

```
..."functionSet": {
        "values": [
          {
            "name": "tester"
          },
          {
            "name": "firstRun"
          }
        ]
      }
```

`testRun()` returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

I can't figure out why the API POST request can't find the function I am calling when it is listed in the GET request.

Here is the API documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest

Comment: Just for clarification, have you already completed the step **'Deploy the script project as an API executable'** on the `tester` function, as outlined in this Google official documentation for [Executing Functions with the Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#requirements)?

Comment: I would like to confirm your situation. In your script, `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` is used. In this case, the Google Apps Script project linked with the Google Cloud Platform project and deployed the setting of "Method: scripts.run" is the Google Apps Script project including your showing script? If that is different, it is required to use the access token of the deployed Google Apps Script project. I'm worried about it. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Both the host script and the remote script that I am trying to run with the host script are part of the same Google Cloud Project.  Both script have been deployed as an API executable, and the Oauth credentials created.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, you want to run one of the functions in the same Google Apps Script project including the function `testRun` using the function `testRun`. Is my understanding correct? By the way, when you reply comment by adding `@usernamme`, the user can notice your reply.

Comment: @Tanaike, Script A is a standalone script file and contains the testRun() function.  Script B is a container bound script file for a Google sheet and contains the tester() function.  In the code provided above, I am trying to use testRun() to execute tester().

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, in this case, I think that it is required to link the Google Cloud Platform project with "Script B" and deploy "API Executable" to "Script B". And, when you want to run `tester()` from "Script A", it is required to use the access token of Google Apps Script project of "Script B". If my understanding of your reply is correct, I think that the reason for your current issue might be related to this situation.

Comment: As a test, please retrieve the access token from "Script B" by `ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`, and hard copy and paste it to "Script A" like `const token = "###"`. And test it again. But, in your script, please include a property of `devMode: true` into `query`. By this, the latest script is used. If this is not used, an old script is used. Please be careful about this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run#request-body) Just in case, please manually save the script of "Script B" with the script editor and deploy "API Executable" to "Script B" again.

Comment: Unfortunately, my proposals are just my guess. So, I posted them as comments. If my comments were not useful, I apologize for this. If my proposals were correct, I would like to post them as an answer by summarizing them.

Comment: @Tanaike, I have it working.  Even though I made no changes to the script after deploying it as an API executable, testerRun() only works if I include devMode: true in the query per your suggestion.  It seems to me this is a bug, and without devmode, it should be running the version of the script that was saved when the executable was created, which it doesn't.  I have also found that cnavar's suggestion to replace the script ID with the deployment ID works and does not require devmode to be turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried replicating your issue and instead of using Script ID, I used the deployment ID of the apps script function that I want to access in the main/primary script.

**Deploy** > **Manage Deployments**

[image]

Give it a try and I'm glad to know how it went!

[Execute Functions with the Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#requirements)

You can also check out this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773410/google-app-script-message-requested-entity-was-not-found-with-devmode), which might be helpful.

Comment: this worked!  It also worked to include devMode: true in the query while still using the script ID.

Comment: I'm glad that this work! Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know that their problem can also be solved with this answer

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function testGet() {
  const scriptId = gobj.globals.scriptid;
  const url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + scriptId + "/content?fields=files(functionSet%2Cname%2Ctype%2Csource)";
  const options = { "method": "get", "headers": { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  let data = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  Logger.log(data)
}
```

Perhaps you need to specify some fields

Comment: I'm not having a problem with the GET method (testGet), but the POST method (testRun)