# Calling a Google App Script function using the API and cURL

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, google-docs

I apologise if this question is too simple but I am a newbie to using cURL. I have created a function in Google App Script to merge text from two Google Docs. The function is this:

```
function mergeGoogleDocs(doc1, doc2) {

var BaseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(doc1);
var body = BaseDoc.getActiveSection();

var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(doc2).getActiveSection();
var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
var type = element.getType();
if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH )
  { 
  body.appendParagraph(element); 
  }
else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
{
body.appendTable(element);
}
else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
{
body.appendListItem(element);
}
else
{
throw new Error("Error de Formato: "+type);
}
}

}
```

I have tested the script and it works perfectly if I put the two document-IDs. I would like to be able to call this function from outside Google using cURL. For this I have enabled all the necessary (credentials, scope permissions, project number and implemented it as an executable API). I've been looking for a way to run the function with cURL and only found this in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892350/apps-script-execution-api-showing-error-with-devmode-true):

```
curl -X POST -L \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d "{function: '### function name ###',devMode: true}" \
    "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run"
```

I need to include the two `document_IDs` as parameters therefore based on the information in the previous post I have created the following sequence:

```
curl -X POST -L \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ##access token##' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"function": "##function name##", "parameters": {"doc1":"##docID1##,"doc2":"##docID2##"}, devMode: true}' \ 
"https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run"
```

But when I run the sequence I get this error message:

```
{
  "done": true,
  "error": {
    "code": 3,
    "message": "ScriptError",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionError",
        "scriptStackTraceElements": [
          {
            "function": "##function name##",
            "lineNumber": 3
          }
        ],
        "errorMessage": "Exception: Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)",
        "errorType": "ScriptError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Could someone please help me to put the sequence correctly for the App Script to work?.

Comment: At first, I deeply apologize that my answer is not useful for your situation. I have a question for your question. Unfortunately, from `I don't know if it will work`, I cannot understand about your current issue. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Comment: I am developing a web application in Xojo and I use libcURL to communicate with Google Drive. I have a folder ('Templates') with several Google Docs that I use as templates. Depending on the user's choice, I need to combine 2 of those documents. As I can't perform this task directly from cURL, I want to use this function in App Script to combine the documents but I need to call the function from Xojo using cURL so I'm asking for help.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike, that's exactly what I needed. Finally I used your first cURL command (modified cURL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to give the values of `##docID1##` and `##docID2##` to the function of `mergeGoogleDocs(doc1, doc2)` in Google Apps Script project.
- You want to run the function using a CURL command.
- In your situation, the preparation for using the method of "scripts.run" in Google Apps Script API has already been finished.
- Your Google Apps Script works fine.

#### Modification points:

- In order to give 2 arguments to `function mergeGoogleDocs(doc1, doc2) {}`, please give the values of value of `##docID1##` and `##docID2##` to the array of `parameters` like `"parameters": ["##docID1##", "##docID2##"]`. In this case, when `"parameters": ["##docID1##", "##docID2##"]` is used, each element of the array is corresponding to each argument for the function in Google Apps Script.
- For example, you want to give the values of `##docID1##` and `##docID2##` to the function as the arguments of `mergeGoogleDocs(doc1, doc2)`, please set the value like `"parameters": ["##docID1##", "##docID2##"]`.
- By the way, in your second curl command, when `{"doc1":"##docID1##,"doc2":"##docID2##"}` is used, `"##docID1##` is not enclosed.

When above points are reflected to your curl command, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified curl command:

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"function": "##function name##", "parameters": ["##docID1##", "##docID2##"], devMode: true}' \
"https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run"
```

#### Note:

- When you want to use `{"doc1":"##docID1##","doc2":"##docID2##"}` as the arcuments, you can also use the following curl command.

  ```
    curl -X POST \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###' \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"function": "##function name##", "parameters": [{"doc1":"##docID1##","doc2":"##docID2##"}], devMode: true}' \
    "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run"
  ```

  - In this case, please modify your script at Google Apps Script side as follows.

    - From

      ```
        function mergeGoogleDocs(doc1, doc2) {
      ```
    - To

      ```
        function mergeGoogleDocs({doc1, doc2}) {
      ```
- When the argument is only one, it seems that `"parameters": "value"` can be used. Namely, I confirmed that the result of `"parameters": "value"` is the same with the result of `"parameters": ["value"]`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: scripts.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run)

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike, that's exactly what I needed. Finally I used your first cURL command (modified cURL)