# Add array as parameter in Google Apps Script function using cURL

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I have created a function in Google Apps Script to create and manage several items in Google Drive (e.g. create a folder, a new Doc or Xls file, etc.). The important thing is that I have 4 DOC documents (or templates): **MainDoc** + **3 additional Doc files**. With my script the MainDoc file is duplicated and renamed (`step1`) and then in a second step the array is defined with the IDs of the 3 additional files that are going to be added/combining their texts on the MainDoc (`step2`).
To make my explanation understandable, I show the basic structure of my function:

```
1    function GlobalWorkflow(ProjectID, mergeDocsID) {
2    ...
3    //### STEP1 ###//
4      var newFolderID = parentFolder.createFolder(date + '_Report').getId();
5      var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolderID);  
6      var docTemplateID = "##MainDocID##";
7      var getDOCTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplateID);
8      var MainDocID = getDOCTemplate.makeCopy(date + '_Report', newFolder).getId();
9    ...
10    //### STEP2 ###//
11      //Input: documentIDs to merge
12      //var mergeDocsID = "##Doc2ID##|##Doc3ID##|##Doc4ID##"
13      var mergeArray = mergeDocsID.split('|');
14      for (var i = 0; i < mergeArray.length; i++) {
15      mergeGoogleDocs(MainDocID, mergeArray[i]);
16     }
17    ...
18    }
```

Line 15 calls another function '`mergeGoogleDocs`' which is fed with 2 parameters. This other function was described in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67038334/calling-a-google-app-script-function-using-the-api-and-curl) and thanks to @Tanaike I managed to run this function from cURL using this command:

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"function": "##function name##", "parameters": ["##docID1##", "##docID2##"], devMode: true}' \
"https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run"
```

The problem I have now is that I want to run the '`GlobalWorkflow`' function but one of the parameters (*mergeDocsID*) is the array with the IDs of the doc files to combine and I get the whole script to work from cURL except that part (`Step2`) although the response doesn't give me an error.

This is the command I used:

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"function": "##function name##", "parameters": ["##MainDocID##", "##Doc2ID##|##Doc3ID##|##Doc4ID##"], devMode: true}' \
"https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run"
```

How could I include the array in the cURL command to make the '`mergeGoogleDocs`' function work?.

PS. If I uncomment line 12 and run the function from GAS everything works perfectly and the combined document with the 4 files is created. What doesn't work is the cURL command.

Could anyone help me?.

Thank you very much.

Wardiam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to give an array like `["##Doc2ID##","##Doc3ID##","##Doc4ID##"]` to `mergeDocsID` of `GlobalWorkflow(ProjectID, mergeDocsID)` using a curl command.
- You have already confirmed that when the correct values are given to the function `GlobalWorkflow`, the script worked fine.
- You have already been able to run a function using Google Apps Script API.

In order to give the array like `["##Doc2ID##","##Doc3ID##","##Doc4ID##"]`, please modify your curl command as follows.

#### From:

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"function": "##function name##", "parameters": ["##MainDocID##", "##Doc2ID##|##Doc3ID##|##Doc4ID##"], devMode: true}' \
"https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run"
```

#### To:

```
curl -X POST \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ### access token ###' \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"function": "##function name##", "parameters": ["##MainDocID##", ["##Doc2ID##","##Doc3ID##","##Doc4ID##"]], devMode: true}' \
"https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/### script ID ###:run"
```

- By above modification, an array of `["##Doc2ID##","##Doc3ID##","##Doc4ID##"]` is given as `mergeDocsID` of `GlobalWorkflow(ProjectID, mergeDocsID)`. So at Google Apps Script side, when above modified curl command is run and `mergeDocsID[0]` is checked, `"##Doc2ID##"` is returned.

#### Reference:

- [Method: scripts.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run)

Comment: Thank you very much Tanaike, it works perfectly. As always, your explanation is perfect and it's just the code I needed. Thanks my friend. ありがとうございました。

Comment: @Wardiam Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank  you, too. こちらこそありがとうございます。